# How to untar in a version agnostic way?

Tags: command-line, tar, wildcards

I want to repetitively untar a file which I often download in new versions; for example:

```
cd download_directory
myFile-1.99.tar.gz # Version 2.x might be released next day or next week or next month;
```

I have tried a similar command with shellglob/wildcard which failed:

```
cd download_directory
tar -xzv myFile-*.tar.gz
```

I also tried the following command after reading the manual about `--wildcards` but it also failed:

```
cd download_directory
tar -xzv myFile-*.tar.gz --wildcards
```

How to untar in a version agnostic way?

Comment: Please provide exact error msgs of your failed attempts.

Comment: @kaylum there were none, even with `set -x`. I just get "endless waiting mode".

Comment: `--wildcards` is not a `tar` option, be careful with nonportable command lines.

Comment: Your '*' is handled *outside* tar, tar gets a lis of all files matching the wildcard, i.e., `myFile-01.tar.gz myFile-03.tar.gz my File-33.tar.gz myFile-br0ken.tar.gz myFile-99.tar.gz`. No wonder it gets confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd download_directory
tar -xzf "$(find . -name 'myFile-*.tar.gz' | tail -n 1)"
```